# Не работает binding SelectedItem listbox

Tags: c#

У меня есть ListBox c электронными сообщениями, я хочу чтобы при двойном клике на элемент этого ListBox мне открывалось новое окно с текстом выбранного сообщения, я сделал так. чтобы при двойном нажатии открывалось новое окно, но как загрузить нужный мне текст сообщения? У меня не получается получить SelectedIndex,то есть при нажатии на элемент SelectedIndex остается равным -1.что я не так делаю? Так как новичок в данном вопросе, очень прошу помощи в решении проблемы
View

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox"
         ItemsSource="{Binding pop, Mode=TwoWay}"
         SelectedIndex="{Binding Path= SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}">
                <TextBlock.InputBindings>
                    <MouseBinding
                        Gesture="LeftDoubleClick"                                          
                       Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window},
                                         Path=DataContext.EnterCommand3}"  />
                </TextBlock.InputBindings>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

ViewModel

```
public class GetMailPopModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ICommand EnterCommand3 { get; set; }
    public ModelPop PopGet { get; set; }
    public ICommand EnterCommand2 { get; set; }
    public MainViewModel mvm = new MainViewModel();
    public Action CloseAction { get; set; }
    public int p {get;set;}

    ListMessage view = new ListMessage();

    public GetMailPopModel()
    {
        Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client();
        EnterCommand3 = new RelayCommand(arg => Mouse());
        pop = new ObservableCollection<ModelPop>();
        PopGet = new ModelPop { };
    }

    private int selectedIndex;
    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedIndex;
        }
        set
        {
            selectedIndex = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedIndex");
        }
    }
   public ObservableCollection<ModelPop> GetMailPop()
    {
        Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client();
        client.Connect("pop.yandex.ru", 995, true);
        client.Authenticate("test.testmy", "qwerty5");

        var Derec = client.GetMessageCount();


        for (int i = Derec; i > 0; i--)
        {

            pop.Add(new ModelPop() { FromP = client.GetMessage(i).Headers.From.Address.ToString() });

        }

        return pop;
    }

    void Mouse()
    {

        ListMessage lv = new ListMessage();

        MessageView mv = new MessageView();
        Selected sel = new Selected();
        mv.DataContext = sel;
        p = SelectedIndex;

        mv.Show();


    }
```

> ViewModelBase.cs

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<ModelPop> pop { get; set; }

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

> ModalPop

```
public class ModelPop : ViewModelBase  
{    
    private string _PopFrom;
    public string PopFrom
    {
        get { return _PopFrom; }
        set
        {

            _PopFrom = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("_PopFrom");
        }
    }

    private string _PopPass;
    public string PopPass
    {
        get { return _PopPass; }
        set
        {
            _PopPass = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("_PopPass");
        }
    }


    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}", FromP);
    }

}
```

> Selected.cs

```
 public class Selected:ViewModelBase
{

    public ModelPop PopGet { get; set; }
    public ICommand EnterCommand2 { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Message> allmessage { get; set; }
    //public ObservableCollection<ModelPop> pop { get; set;}
    GetMailPopModel d = new GetMailPopModel();
    public Message message { get; set; }

    Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client();


    public Selected()
    {
        Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client();
        allmessage = new ObservableCollection<Message>();
        PopGet = new ModelPop { };
        PopGet.builder = new StringBuilder();

        GetMailPop();
        //Get();

    }

    public string GetMailPop()

    {
        Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client();
        client.Connect("pop.yandex.ru", 995, true);
        client.Authenticate("test.testmy", "qwerty5");

        var Derec = client.GetMessageCount();


        for (int i = Derec; i > 0; i--)
        {

            allmessage.Add(client.GetMessage(i));


        }


        Message message = client.GetMessage(d.p);
```

Comment: Ваши свойства в VM не реализуют INotifyPropertyChanged. Это уже ошибка. Для начала исправьте её и посмотрите, решится ли ваша проблема. Возможно, понадобятся дальнейшие улучшения.

Comment: И в вашем коде нету Binding на SelectedIndex. (И «я новичок» у нас тут не канает. Не знаете основ — прочитайте книгу и приходите.)

Comment: Я не показал здесь реализацию, выглядит так, может в ней ошибка.    <pre>   private SelectedItem selectedItem;
        public SelectedIndex SelectedIndex
        {
            get
            {
                return selectedIndex;
            }
            set
            {
                selectedIndex = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedIndex");
            }
        } <code>   
Следовательно в xaml добавил 
SelectedIndex="{Binding Path= SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" Правильно ли я понял?

Comment: Вроде бы правильно. Но лучше добавьте ваш код в вопрос (его можно редактировать), а то здесь сложно читать.

Comment: И у вас в XAML'е `ItemsSource="{Binding pop, Mode=TwoWay}"`, а в .cs такого свойства не видно — может, это ошибка?

Comment: Дополнил. просто изначально весь код не писал, pop это моя коллекция сообщений.

Comment: Странно, а её всё ещё нету в виде свойства. Допишите его, а?

Comment: Прописано в другом классе, добавил класс.

Comment: Окей, теперь намного лучше. Итак, ваш код приходит на doubleclick в `Mouse()`, и чему там равен `SelectedIndex`? (Кстати, вы почему-то читаете `SelectedIndex` не из свойства, а перечитываете его из `ListView`. Но это отдельный разговор.)

Comment: Когда переходит в метод Mouse(), я пытаюсь присвоить переменной р SelectedIndex 
где lv.listBox это мой листбокс, если я правильно понимаю вопрос.

Comment: Ну да. И чт опри этом в переменной `p`? По идее, вы могли бы просто написать `p = SelectedIndex`, у вас же есть привязка. Но снова непонятно, (1) где и как объявлено `p`, и (2) как оно будет доступно в `mv`? `Selected` ведь ничего не знает о `p`.

Comment: p прописал как свойство.public int p {get;set;} в  GetMailPopModel, а в Selected cоздал обьект того класса и прописал как d.p, где d - обьект класса GetMailPopModel. Я правильно понял?

Comment: Ну, теперь смотрите. В `mv` у вас `DataContext` — экземпляр `Selected`. Откуда он знает о `p`?

Comment: Понял! Занес  р в конструктор и все заработало! Спасибо большое!

Comment: Пожалуйста! Перенесу обсуждение в ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала, в функции `Mouse()` можно пользоваться полем `this.SelectedIndex`, а не вычитывать его из `ListView`.

Затем, у вас создаётся новый экземпляр класса `Selected`, который ничего не знает о `p`, поэтому ему этот `p` нужно передать.

Затем, судя по всему, `Selected` перечитывает сообщения по новой, хотя в принципе можно было бы ему их передать в том же конструкторе (они ведь есть на тот момент в классе `GetMailPopModel`! Обратите внимание, что вы в `Selected` зачем-то создаёте **ещё один** экземпляр `GetMailPopModel`, это в принципе не должно быть нужно.